# Jest coverage says if statement is uncovered but I'm testing both positive and negative cases

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

pretty straightforward question here. I have the following function that I'm testing (edited for brevity) and my code coverage tool (using Jest) says that the return in the if conditional is uncovered. Does anyone know why that might be? I'm making assertions against the conditional evaluating to true, and I'm asserting against the final result of the function when the conditional is false. Changing the return value fails the first two tests like I would expect, and changing the final return value fails the last test. What more does it want?

```js
const doThing = (param1: any, param2: any) => {
    if (!param1) {
        return '';
    }
    ...more stuff
    return theResult;
}
```

and the following tests

```js
        it('should return empty for no param1', () => {
            const result = doThing(undefined, param2);

            expect(result).toEqual('');
        });

        it('should return empty for null param1', () => {
            const result = doThing(null, param2);

            expect(result).toEqual('');
        });

        it('should return thing when param1 exists', () => {
            const result = doThing(param1, param2);

            expect(result).toEqual('a real value');
        });
```

Comment: I can suggest doing two things; first attempt to debug or alternatively add a ```console.log``` statement inside ```if (!param1) {``` to see if the inside is actually being hit during the execution of the test suite. If the former does not work I would secondly recommend testing it with ```0``` and ```false``` to see if that will make any difference - theoretically it shouldn't but what you are seeing is out of the ordinary to begin with.

Comment: I also tend to add extra checks in my main code. If I do not want null, undefined, etc., I tend to have if statements to validate against this, instead of the more open ended one you have.  I am guessing there is simply something returned on !param1 when it is undefined, or in another state.